# TestRail API endpoint update_user/:user_id returning HTTP 404("Unknown method 'update_user'")

Tags: java, testrail

I am attempting to use the TestRail API to update a user using endpoint: `POST index.php?/api/v2/update_user/:user_id`. I am receiving an error `TestRail API returned HTTP 404("Unknown method 'update_user'")`. I am using the Java API client and TestRail version 7.0.2.1016

I am able to get a successful return on some of the different API methods (such as get user, get user by id/email, add/update/delete project). I believe some endpoints may not be compatible with my version of TestRail based on the API docs but can't find anything in the API docs to suggest that would apply to this `update_user` endpoint. However, if that is the case, is there another endpoint to update the user compatible with my current version? Example request below.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("role", "Guest");

JSONObject result = (JSONObject) client.sendPost("update_user/213", map);
```

Comment: You have a typo in URL - it should be `index.php?/api/v2/update_user/`, not `index.php?/api/vs/update_user/`  (**v2** not **vs**)

Comment: That was a typo in transcribing my question, I fixed it thank you @Sergi

Comment: From the API i guess you should call it with PUT, not POST

Comment: @SurPrise2 The API handles all change requests (including updates and deletes) with a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully updated the user with the help of "update_user" end point in TestRail version 8.0.1 without encountering any issues. My client of choice for this process was POSTMAN.

It was a POST request with the below endpoint

```
https://{TESTRAIL_INSTANCE}/index.php?/api/v2/update_user/{USER_ID}
```

The request body looks like below (as in this case I only wanted to change the the name of the user)

```
{
    "name": "ABCD"
}
```

and I got the 200 as a response and the name of the user was updated successfully.

So, the end point is working fine without any issue. For more details you can refer to the below documentation available in TestRail
[Update User](https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/7077978310292-Users#updateuser)

Furthermore, could you please attempt this using TestRail 8.0 and confirm whether the issue lies with your code or the TestRail version?